# Woocommerce custom log in and register

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

How to edit and design the login and register of the default woocommerce and make it more modern and more stylish which can fits more an online store thanks alot for the help

Comment: There's a lot of ways to go about doing this.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy woocommerce templates in your current active theme like theme->woocommerce and put the all templates and modified myaccount/form-login.php